# How to append a table with cells that contain clickable SPANs

Tags: jquery, html-table, onclick, append

With jQuery 1.7x, I'm creating whole tables within dynamically generated tabs that have several columns, some of which need to be clickable.

Everything seems to be wonderful except that elusive click event on dynamic content.  I just learned how to do this for list items by using the .on method, but it doesn't seem to work for my tables.  (If it matters, each jQuery tab is dynamically added for a given year, and the table on that tab contains all meetings held that year)

What am I missing? I've got this at http://jsfiddle.net/KYkRZ/

```
<table>
     <tr><td><span class="ClickableClass">Is Clickable</span></td><td>Regular TD</td></tr>
</table>
<div id='myTab'></div>

$('.ClickableClass').on('click',function() {alert("ClickableClass click event") });

$('#myTab').append('<table border></table>');
var myTable = $('#myTab').children();
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   var mySpan = $('<span></span>').addClass('ClickableClass').text('Should be clickable ' + i);
    var myTD = $('<td></td>').append( mySpan );
    var myTR = $('<tr></tr>').append( myTD );
   $(myTable).append( myTR );
}
```

Also, I don't know that this is the best way to construct a table on the fly, but it was the clearest for me to understand, so any suggestions to that end would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the event handlers to the objects, then creating new ones and never adding event handlers to the new ones. There are two ways you can deal with this. The first is just to add event handlers after each, but that duplicates code. If you know you're going to have dynamic content the better approach is to add the event handler to the container and tell the container to look for the click event in an element of a specific type by passing a selector to the event.

```
$('body').on('click', '.ClickableClass', function() {
    alert("ClickableClass click event"); 
});
```

Comment: Ah, I see...I'm beginning to "get" this whole jquery thing, but after the syntax itself, the where/when always seems to trip me up.  I cannot express how very much I appreciate people like you that are willing to lend a helping hand to those of us still trying to get there.  Also, is the code I supplied suitable for appending mulitple TDs (about 10 of them), or would there be a better approach than this sample code to understand the event handling

Comment: Happy to assist - these forums helped me greatly getting started as well so I'm glad to return the favor where possible. Regarding your code approach, whether it is the best way or not depends on your ultimate purpose but if what you're looking for is a simple way for the user to be able to click on the table rows and fire an event then this approach works fine. As you append lots of stuff to the same container, you are definitely going to want to attach the event handler to the container as we did here vs each item for performance reasons if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem where in the order of the parameters of the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$('body').on('click', '.ClickableClass', function() {
   alert("ClickableClass click event"); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KYkRZ/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myTab').on('click', 'span.ClickableClass', function() {alert("ClickableClass click event") });
$('#myTab').append('<table border></table>');
var myTable = $('#myTab').children();
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    var mySpan = $('<span></span>').addClass('ClickableClass').text('Should be clickable ' + i);
    var myTD = $('<td></td>').append( mySpan );
    var myTR = $('<tr></tr>').append( myTD );
    $(myTable).append( myTR );
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KYkRZ/6/)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can bind click event to your span:

```
var mySpan =
    $('<span></span>')
        .addClass('ClickableClass')
        .bind('click', function() { alert('it works'); })
        .text('Should be clickable ' + i);
```

Comment: Ah, the .bind event.  This always "confuses" me, perhaps because of the examples I see it used in.  I don't understand why one would put the function being bound in with the binding itself.  Can you bind to an event already defined elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Just for a slightly more optimized way, you could cache your variables as well as eliminate the unnecessary jQuery objects in your for loop.

***[I would do it this way:](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/wr5Hu/)***

```
var $body = $("body"),
    $myTab = $("#myTab").append("<table border></table>").children();

$body.on("click", ".ClickableClass", function() {
    alert($(this).html().trim()); 
});

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
   $myTab.append("<tr><td><span class=\"ClickableClass\">Should be clickable " 
                 + i + "</span></td></tr>");    
}
```